# CLLocationManager does not initialize on viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, geolocation

I have a simple `objective C` app with `UIWebView`. This is loading an URL in `viewDidLoad` method and I need to localize this URL **BEFORE** the `loadRequest` but my `CLLocationManager` is calling the `didUpdateToLocation` method **AFTER** the `loadRequest`.

My `viewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // execute super method
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // put gray background color
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    // define itself as UIWebView delegate
    self.webView.delegate = self;

    // define itself as CLLocationManager delegate
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    NSLog(@"LOCALIZED????%@",[self getCustomURL:homeURL]);
    [self.webView loadRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self getCustomURL:homeURL]]]];
}
```

I'm always getting (null) when calling `loadRequest`, but just after i'm getting the correct location.

I've tried to separate in a new thread the `startUpdatingLocation`

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
});
```

Or waiting till getting a correct location:

```
while (longitude == nil) {
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Any idea how can I get the location before the `loadRequest` to have the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use loadRequest in method from CLLocationManagerDelegate:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    ……
    ……
    [self.webView loadRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self getCustomURL:homeURL]]]];
    ……
    ……
}
```

Also, in iOS8, you need to do couple things to get location:

**1)** Call requestWhenInUseAuthorization method before startUpdatingLocation:

```
if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
   [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

**2)** add *NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription* or *NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription* key to Info.plist.

Answer (score 2):

`CLLocationManager` is an async task. To execute the loadRequest after the location, you need to implement the delegate for the `CLLocationManager` and then call the loadRequest on the webview